# Call the class child method not its grandchild method

Tags: php, oop, abstract-class

My problem is that REQ class will call the REQ_User's get() method instead of user's get() method.

Is it posseble to make the REQ class call REQ_User's get() method.
Or is this a bad OOP design? Is there a better OOP design that I can do?

REQ is the main router that handle the general routes.

```
abstract class REQ{
    function get(){die('get() is not available');}
    function get_id($id){die('get_id() is not available');}
    function __construct(){
        http_response_code(500);//We dont know if its gonna be an unknown error in the future.
        if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']==='GET' && isset($_GET['id']))
            $this->get_id( (int)$_GET['id'] );
        elseif( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']==='GET' )
            //Heres is the actual problem of my question.
            //This will call the youngest child class which is user's get() method.
            //I need it to call the REQ_User's get() method instead.
            $this->get();

        //Much more routes is supposed to be here like post,delete,put etc. But this is just a example.
    }
}
```

**REQ_User** adds more abilities than REQ can do. Abilities that is specialized only for user manager classes.

```
abstract class REQ_User extends REQ{
    function session(){die('session() is not available');}
    function get(){//I need this method to be called instead of user's get() method.
        if(isset($_GET['session'])){
            $this->session();
        }else{//Call either its parent or its child but never its self.
            if(get_class($this) === __CLASS__) parent::get();
            else $this->get();
        }
    }
}
```

**REQ_Comment** adds more abilities than REQ can do. Abilities that is specialized only for comment manager classes.

```
abstract class REQ_Comment extends REQ{
    function byuser($id){die('byuser() is not available');}
    function get(){
        if(isset($_GET['byuser'])) $this->byuser( (int)$_GET['id'] );
        else{//Call either its parent or its child but never its self.
            if(get_class($this) === __CLASS__) parent::get();
            else $this->get();
        }
    }
}
```

*Note that get() will not call its self but only its parent or its child depends if the child got the method get() or not.

The actual logic comes in in these classes. The top classes.
These classes are super specialized.

```
class user extends REQ_User{
    //If no url parameter is set then this will get a collection of users.
    function get(){
        http_response_code(200);
        die('user1,user2...');
    }
    function session(){
        http_response_code(200);
        session_start();
        die(json_encode($_SESSION['user']));
    }
};
class comment extends REQ_Comment{
    function byuser($id){//Specialized route only for comments based classes.
        http_response_code(200);
        die('comment1,comment2... by user '.$id);
    }
    function get_id($id){//This comes directly from REQ class.
        http_response_code(200);
        die('user '.$id);
    }
};

//new comment();
//new user();
```

Comment: You could possible do that by defining abstract methods that must be implemented by children classes.

Answer (score 1):

call `parent::get()` from within the `get` method of `user` if both should be called. Otherwise you should just give the method in `user` another name.

Regarding your OO design: I don't understand the purpose of your code but the fact alone that you have to ask this question hints at bad design, yes. Also: probably wrong usage of inheritance, mixture of responsibilities, unclear naming...

And this will result in infinite recursion if $_GET['session'] is not set (the method calls itself):

```
function get(){
    echo 'REQ_user method';
    if(isset($_GET['session'])){
        $this->session();
    }else{
        $this->get();
    }
```

Comment: Its very hard to explain the design but i will update the code and correct the infinite recursion problem. Maybe it will clear the idea of the design. It is supposed to eliminate dublicate code and have some sort of standard interface for different type of manager classes.

Comment: Both need to be called in right order yes. The principle is that the parent can only call its child and that child can only call its child etc, instead of jumping over and call its grandchild. Adding parent::get() dont solve the problem becaus child will call its parent and that parent will call its child resulting in infinite recursion  also.